# How to simulate IME ACTION in an UiObject2 from UiAutomator?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I have an UiObject2 that represents an EditText:

```
UiObject2 objSearch = TestHelper.findObjectById("textSearch");
```

I want to simulate the IME ACTION of this object programmatically. There is no method in `UiObject2` that let me get the view and transform in EditText.

How can I simulate IME ACTION in the `objSearch`?

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution:

```
device.pressEnter();
```

Where `device` is your `UiDevice`.